# Cloudify get workflow's blueprint_id and deployment_id

Tags: workflow, cloudify

How do I get blueprint_id and deployment_id in my own custom workflow in Cloudify?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python you can do this:

```
from cloudify.workflows import ctx

blueprint_id = ctx.blueprint.id
deployment_id = ctx.deployment.id
```